# Remove record based on id passed in the url using mongoose with mongodb in a handlebars project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars/express/mongodb project where I am able to save and create users who can save and create a trip itinerary. I am trying to remove (delete) a particular itinerary. I have a user model and a trip model in a one to many relationship. The front end uses handlebars as the template. I am able to save multiple trips for the same user and display them. I am trying to delete one trip based on its id passed through the url. The trip, of course, has a unique id as assigned by mongodb.

My front end handlebars code looks like this and is a handlebars partial:

```
<form action="trips/itinerary/delete/{{this._id}}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">

    <button type="submit" class="submit">DELETE!</button>
</form>
```

My js code using mongoose to remove in my logic file (where creating new trips and rendering them is working just fine) looks like this:

```
router.delete('/delete/:_id', function(req,res) {
    Trip.remove(
        { _id: req.params._id }
    )
    // connect it to this .then.
        .then(function() {
            res.redirect('/itinerary');
        })
});
```

I am getting a not found error, although it is throwing the trip _id into the url. I am thinking the issue is with my use of params? I cannot seem to find a clear example of how to do this using all the tools I am using in this project.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the id from the client to a valid ObjectId, or use findByIdAndRemove function, this function accepts a String, a ObjectId or a numebr so is more easy to use.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove